# django-import-export: cannot exclude id field during import : KeyError: u'id'

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

On Django-1.9.6, django-import-export-0.5

When I try to upload CSV without "id" field throws this error.

```
Line number: 1 - u'id'
13173474, Harry McDade, 10.harry.asas@asasasas.com
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/isanka/dev/venv/edxubase/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 434, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/Users/isanka/dev/venv/edxubase/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 258, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/Users/isanka/dev/venv/edxubase/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 252, in get_instance
return instance_loader.get_instance(row)
File "/Users/isanka/dev/venv/edxubase/lib/python2.7/site-packages/import_export/instance_loaders.py", line 31, in get_instance
field = self.resource.fields[key]
KeyError: u'id'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems "django-import-export" still using the default one 'id'. for the time been, included a column 'id' in the header in CSV file and excluded importing in resources.py

```
class edxUserResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = edxUser
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
        exclude = ('id',)
        import_id_fields = ('edx_id', 'edx_email', 'edx_name',)
        #export_order = ('edx_id', 'edx_email')
```

Comment: we can exclude the id, if we want to

Answer (score 1):

The id field is an auto increment field, so if you're adding new records (I believe its the most case) the id field should be there in the header (first line of csv file) and the rest of the rows should contain empty id like : ,

Example:

```
CSV File:
id, username,email,password
,ahmad,ahmad@all.com,secretum
,salafi,salafi@gmail.com,Passhdjdj

In the Resource file (py):
class JasResult(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = JasResource
    skip_unchanged = True
    report_skipped = True
    exclude = ('id',)
    import_id_fields = ('username','email','password')
```

This should fine for most cases.

Comment: Thanks this really helped :)

Answer (score 0):

i have figure out the solution to import without ID column 
Here is code , Take a Look

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
    queryset = Client.objects.filter(company=company)
    company = Company.objects.get(id=company)
    person_resource = ClientResource()
    dataset = Dataset()
    new_persons = request.FILES['myfile']
    imported_data = dataset.load(new_persons.read().decode('utf-8'), format='csv')
    try:
        for row in dataset:
            client = Client()
            client.company = company
            client.title = row[0]
            client.first_name = row[1]
            client.last_name = row[2]
            client.email = row[3]
            client.position = row[4]
            client.company_name = row[5]
            client.vat_number = row[6]
            client.website = row[7]
            client.address = row[8]
            client.city = row[9]
            client.state = row[10]
            client.zip = row[11]
            client.country = row[12]
            client.phone = row[13]
            client.fax = row[14]
            client.notes = row[15]
            client.save()

    except Client.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404("There is a Problem with The CSV")

return render(request, 'import.html')
```

And my Resource Looks Like this

```
class ClientResource(resources.ModelResource):
company = fields.Field(
    column_name='company',
    attribute='company',
    widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Company, 'name'))

class Meta:
    model = Client
    skip_unchanged = True
    report_skipped = True
    exclude = ('id', 'company', 'status', 'modified', 'created')
    import_id_fields = ['email']
```

Answer (score 0):

Add import_id_fields to your class Meta, like this

```
class Meta:
    exclude = ('id', 'avatar')
    import_id_fields = ('analytical_id',)
    model = Employee
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).