# Django import-export KeyError: u'id'

Tags: jquery, django, python-3.x, django-import-export

Couldn't able to exclude the ID, even tried with the existing question in stackoverflow: [django-import-export: cannot exclude id field during import : KeyError: u'id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45028975/django-import-export-cannot-exclude-id-field-during-import-keyerror-uid)

***resource.py***

```
from import_export import resources
from .models import Bugdata

class BugDataResource(resources.ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = Bugdata
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
        exclude = ('id',)
        import_id_fields = ['Created_date', 'BugID', 'ID_Link', 'Summary', 'Status', 'Severity', 'Tags']
```

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models

class Bugdata(models.Model):
    Created_date = models.DateField()
    BugID = models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    ID_Link = models.URLField(max_length=300)
    Summary = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Severity = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Tags = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Summary
```

***admin.py***

```
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin
from .models import Bugdata
# Register your models here.

@admin.register(Bugdata)
class NewtaskAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    pass
```

Traceback

```
Error:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gomathis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
  packages\django_import_export-1.0.1-py3.6.egg\import_export\resources.py", 
  line 453, in import_row
  instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
  File "C:\Users\gomathis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
  packages\django_import_export-1.0.1-py3.6.egg\import_export\resources.py", 
  line 267, in get_or_init_instance
  instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
  File "C:\Users\gomathis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
  packages\django_import_export-1.0.1-py3.6.egg\import_export\resources.py", 
  line 261, in get_instance
  return instance_loader.get_instance(row)
  File "C:\Users\gomathis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
  packages\django_import_export-1.0.1- 
  py3.6.egg\import_export\instance_loaders.py", line 31, in get_instance
  field = self.resource.fields[key]
  KeyError: 'id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I don't have the reputation to add a comment, did you resolve this? I was having something similar occur with the same setup as yourself, so one suggestion is to double check the encoding of the file you are impording. I have had issues with Excel on a Mac saving to CSV format, in this case I used a text editor such as sublime to make sure it's saved to UTF8 format and that particular error seemed to disappear.